# Prove $F[x]/(x^n)$ is an injective module

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, homological-algebra, injective-module

Let $F$ be a field and $n\geq1$

(1) Prove $R=F[x]/(x^n)$ is an injective $R$-module.

(2) Give a projective resolution and an injective resolution of the $R$-submodule $M=(x)/(x^n)$

For part (1), I know that by Baer's criterion, it suffices to show for all ideals $(x^k)/(x^n)\ $ ($k\leq n$) that the inclusion

$$\iota:(x^k)/(x^n)\to F[x]/(x^n)$$
has a left inverse. But I don't know how to construct one. I have proven that $\iota(x^k+(x^n))$ has the form
$$\iota(x^k)+(x^n)=a_kx^k+a_{k+1}x^{k+1}+\cdots+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+(x^n),\quad a_k\neq0$$
and tried to work from there.

For part (2) I don't have a clue.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have access to Rotman's Intro to Homological Algebra? There is a nice proof of 1 on page 174 (proposition 4.37). If not I can type up a solution.

Comment: I have the digital access to the book from the school library, and have solved part (1) with it. Thanks very much. And can you offer some hints on part (2)?

Comment: Do you mean $F[x]$ instead of$F(x)$?

Comment: Yes thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expansion $R\to R$ can be constructed by mapping $1$ to $a_k+a_{k+1}x+\cdots+a_{n-1}x^{n-1-k}$ (and I think k need not divide n).

The projective resolution is a series of $R$'s and maps are multiplication of $x$ and $x^{n-1}$ alternatively, ending by $x$ to the ideal. 
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    ... @>x^{n-1}>> R@>x>>R@>x^{n-1}>>R@>x>>\mathcal{a}
\end{CD}
The injective one is similar, and begin by inclusion.

Comment: I think you mean $F[x]$ instead of $F(x)$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake. Also, I am wondering whether there's some routine of finding a projective/injective resolution. Can you explain the thought or offer me some references?

Comment: Technically, for any R-module $M$, we can always construct a free module $P_0$by letting the basis be the generators of $M$, and thus we get a projection. Find its kernel and similarly we get $P_1$ and all the following parts. In this case, $R$ itself is obviously projective and there is the obvious projection $\pi: 1\mapsto x$, and the kernel is also clear, and the following steps are easy.  And for the injective resolution, if the construction is not obvious, we can use the theorem of Enough Injectives. But here the inclusion to the injective module $R$ is ok.

Answer (score 1):

My favourite proof for (1) uses the vector space duality $D:=\mathrm{Hom}_F(-,F)$. It is easy to see that a finite dimensional $R$-module $X$ is projective (respectively invective) if and only if $D(X)$ is injective (respectively projective).

Now consider the map
$$ \tau \in D(R), \quad a_0+a_1x+\cdots+a_{n-1}x^{n-1} \mapsto a_{n-1}. $$
Then $\tau$ induces an isomorphism of $R$-modules $R\xrightarrow\sim D(R)$, $1\mapsto\tau$. Since it is clear that $R$ is projective, we see that it is also injective. In fact, this shows that $R$ is a symmetric algebra.

For (2) we can construct an exact sequence
$$ 0 \to M \to R \xrightarrow{f} R \to M \to 0, $$
where $f\colon 1\mapsto x^{n-1}$. This is then the start of both a projective resolution of $M$, and an injective coresolution. Since it repeats, we can continue this in either direction to get the full (co-)resolution.